# Flexbox problems - Firefox and IE10/11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

i don't get the problems in the flex-markup i got in a small tile-styled layout (using bootstrap and i added flex-row-classes).

in chrome, safari, opera, and even on mobile devices it works like it should. except for IE10/11 and current Firefox (44.0.2).

i get bugs for the 4 column-layout, where they don't collapse after the breakpoint is reached, instead the images staying bigger than they should (maxing out of the max-width) and i don't know why.

it would be awesome if someone could help me!

thank you in advance!

code:

```js
$(".readmore").click(function() {
      $(this).next(".expand").addClass("expanded");
    });
    $(".closebox").click(function() {
      $(this).parent(".expanded").removeClass("expanded");
    });
```

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
    .col-xs-1,
    .col-sm-1,
    .col-md-1,
    .col-lg-1,
    .col-xs-2,
    .col-sm-2,
    .col-md-2,
    .col-lg-2,
    .col-xs-3,
    .col-sm-3,
    .col-md-3,
    .col-lg-3,
    .col-xs-4,
    .col-sm-4,
    .col-md-4,
    .col-lg-4,
    .col-xs-5,
    .col-sm-5,
    .col-md-5,
    .col-lg-5,
    .col-xs-6,
    .col-sm-6,
    .col-md-6,
    .col-lg-6,
    .col-xs-7,
    .col-sm-7,
    .col-md-7,
    .col-lg-7,
    .col-xs-8,
    .col-sm-8,
    .col-md-8,
    .col-lg-8,
    .col-xs-9,
    .col-sm-9,
    .col-md-9,
    .col-lg-9,
    .col-xs-10,
    .col-sm-10,
    .col-md-10,
    .col-lg-10,
    .col-xs-11,
    .col-sm-11,
    .col-md-11,
    .col-lg-11,
    .col-xs-12,
    .col-sm-12,
    .col-md-12,
    .col-lg-12 {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .row-flex,
    .row-flex > div[class*='col-'] {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
    .row-flex-wrap {
      -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      align-content: flex-start;
      flex: 0;
    }
    .row-flex > div[class*='col-'],
    .container-flex > div[class*='col-'] {
      /*margin:-.2px; /* hack adjust for wrapping */
    }
    .container-flex > div[class*='col-'] div,
    .row-flex > div[class*='col-'] div {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .flex-col {
      display: flex !important;
      display: -webkit-flex !important;
      flex: 1 100%;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .flex-grow {
      display: flex;
      -webkit-flex: 2;
      flex: 2;
    }
    .contentbox {
      min-height: 292px !important;
    }
    @media (min-width: 480px) {
      .contentbox {
        min-height: 200px !important;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .contentbox {
        min-height: 160px !important;
      }
    }
    .contentbox {
      padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
      height: auto;
      min-height: 160px;
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    .readmore {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .contentbox h2 {
      font-variant: small-caps;
    }
    .expand {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      font-size: 15px;
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      transition: all .75s ease-in-out;
      border-bottom: 2px solid $primary;
    }
    .expanded {
      top: 0;
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      cursor: default;
      transition: all .75s ease-in-out;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    }
    .closebox {
      font-size: 24px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      top: 0px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .shadow {
      box-shadow: 0px 4px 12px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container shadow">
  <div class="row row-flex row-flex-wrap">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 fw">
      <div class="contentbox readmore bgr flex-col">
        <h2>example</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="contentbox expand bgr flex-col">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="pull-right closebox">×</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanct</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">read more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
      <div class="imagecontainer">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/887x898" alt="Beispielinhalt" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-sm-block"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
      <div class="imagecontainer">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/887x898" alt="Beispielinhalt" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bgb fw">
      <div class="contentbox readmore flex-col">
        <h2>example</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="contentbox expand bgb flex-col">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="pull-right closebox">×</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanct</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">read more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-flex row-flex-wrap">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
      <div class="imagecontainer">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1325x907" alt="Beispielinhalt" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bgp fw">
      <div class="contentbox readmore flex-col">
        <h2>example</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="contentbox expand bgp flex-col">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="pull-right closebox">×</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanct</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">read more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-flex row-flex-wrap">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 fw">
      <div class="contentbox readmore bgr flex-col">
        <h2>example</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="contentbox expand bgr flex-col">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="pull-right closebox">×</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanct</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">read more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
      <div class="imagecontainer">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/887x898" alt="Beispielinhalt" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-sm-block"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bgb fw">
      <div class="contentbox readmore flex-col">
        <h2>example</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="contentbox expand bgb flex-col">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="pull-right closebox">×</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanct</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">read more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
      <div class="imagecontainer">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/887x898" alt="Beispielinhalt" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

bootply: http://www.bootply.com/UGEHVTvNXi

Where the mistake happens: If you resize IE10/11/FF44.0.2 you will see the bug. the cols should collapse but it only works for the 8er/4er-col-combo. if the row contains 4x3 cols it doesn't work properly not even with added clearfix.

Comment: Why would you need a clearfix for flexbox?

Comment: cause the col-classes from bootstrap still floating - and i thought maybe that causes the error.

Comment: ie has bugs with flex + min-height : http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: flex-items don't require clearing.

Comment: GCYrillus: I know that, and IE is not really the main reason to get this fixed but the firefox should actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used only the webkit vendor prefix, firefox won't use the rule.
Change .row-flex-wrap to the following and it should work.

```
.row-flex-wrap {
      -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      align-content: flex-start;
      flex: 0;
    }
```

Best

Comment: so easy. must have been blind to overlook this. THANK YOU!

Comment: i have another problem with this stuff. i don't know if you can help, but i wanted to ask before i'm doing a complete new question: in Safari, the col-sm-6-DIVs are collapsing way too early (even before 992er breakpoint) so i have two fullwidth divs. in FF, Chrome, IE9 and Opera the boxes are collapsing right where they should. in IE10/11 and Safari 9 (on iPad) they collapse too early (in case of Safari) or never collapse (IE10/11). how can i fix this?